# Why is this Perl CGI script failing to upload images correctly?

Tags: html, perl, image, upload, cgi

I have this code:

```
use CGI;    
use File::Basename;    
use Image::Magick;    
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);    
my $query = new CGI;    
my $upload_dir = "../images"; #location on our server    
my $filename=$query->param("img");    
my $timestamp = int (gettimeofday * 1000);    
my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*' );     
$filename = $name ."_".$timestamp. $extension;    

 #upload the image

my $upload_filehandle =$query->param("img");    
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";  
 binmode UPLOADFILE;  
 while ( <$upload_filehandle> )  
  {  
   print UPLOADFILE;  
   }  

  close UPLOADFILE;
```

Then I do resize for the image. My problem is that the image is not uploaded. I have an empty file having the name of $filename. I omitted the part related to resize and I still have the code. So I'm sure that the file is not being uploaded correctly. Am I missing any library?
Any help?Plz..

Comment: Some recommendations: (1) Avoid indirect object notation. I.e.: use `CGI->new`. (2) Don't use relative paths for upload locations unless you have specifically changed to a known directory. (3) Some of use find `$filename = "${name}_$timestamp$extension";` or even `$filename = sprintf '%s_%d%s', $name, $timestamp, $extension;` more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why: As pointed out in the [CGI.pm docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI#CREATING_A_FILE_UPLOAD_FIELD), the form's encoding type **must** be `multipart/form-data`. When I added that, everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

`my $upload_filehandle =$query->param("img");`

to

`my $upload_filehandle =$query->upload("img");`

according to [this tutorial](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/uploading-files-cgi-perl/2).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did not work. When I print "|$upload_filehandle|" i get it ||.
which means that the uploaded file is empty. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

added this "ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'" instead of encoding.

```
> <form action="/post.pl" method="post"  ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'>
```

and it worked