# CGI script cant create file

Tags: perl, file, permissions, cgi

I have the following CGI script that launches a module that creates a PNG file and then shows it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use RRDs;
use CGI;

main:
{
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $filename = $cgi->param('filename');
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $curr_time = time();
my $start_time = $curr_time-3600;
RRDs::graph("$filename", "--start", "$start_time", "DEF:DiskC=c.rrd:DiskC:AVERAGE", "AREA:DiskC#0000FF");
my $err = RRDs::error();
print "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Disk C Utilization</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Disk C Utilization</H1><BR>$err<img src=\"$filename\"/></BODY></HTML>";
}
```

The graph method says that can't create the PNG file. If I run this script in a command like it works fine so I think it's a matter of permissions. I already set chmod 755 on the cgi-script folder. What do you suggest? Is this related to Apache2 settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod 777` solved my problem!

Comment: Are there any other users on that server?

Answer (score 3):

Um, check the logs :) [CGI Help Guide](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=165253)

$filename is not the filename that you want to use , it can be anything the browser sends, even `F:/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/UHOH.png`

Its unlikely that `F:/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/UHOH.png` exists on your server

You want to **generate** a filename, maybe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770176/perl-script-for-file-upload/7777321)

```
sub WashFilename {
    use File::Basename;
    my $basename = basename( shift );
    # untainted , only use a-z A-Z 0-9 and dot
    $basename = join '', $basename =~ m/([.a-zA-Z0-9])/g;
    # basename is now, hopefully, file.ext
    ## so to ensure uniqueness, we adulterate it :)
    my $id = $$.'-'.time;
    my( $file, $ext ) = split /\./, $basename, 2 ;
    return join '.', grep defined, $file, $id, $ext;
} ## end sub WashFilename
```

You also want to place the file in a directory of your webserver that will serve images (NOT cgi-bin)

And you also want to use `File::Type::WebImages` to *determine web image file types using magic* and make sure the filename has the appropriate extension , so your server will send the appropriate headers

And don't forget to `chmod` the file appropriately

Comment: Well this script is a test actually, ofcourse directory and checks will be different once I set up everything. Anyway the parameter received is just the filename (ie test.png) not the entire path. I assume cgi-script as the default path right now.

Comment: If you're just running the script yourself to test it, then you probably don't have to worry much about sanitizing the filename. But before you put this in production, make ABSOLUTELY SURE that you've changed the code to handle filenames correctly. As proctor said, you want to make sure users can't include directories in filenames. Also, you have an XSS vulnerability in your print statement. If the user gives a filename of `"/><script>alert("Hello");</script><"` (including the quotes), then you're done for. If you assume the user is malicious, then you'll be in a better position security-wise.

Comment: Turn on Perl's taint mode if you haven't already.  It's not perfect, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Actually the script cannot be called from the outside and the output is just a little test to check the image immediatly, in fact the PNG will be opened from a much larger (and secure ofcourse) webpage ^^

Answer (score 0):

Don't store a document to file unless you have a reason to: it's slow and introduces all kinds of potential hazards.

You don't appear to reuse the same image on different requests, which might be such a reason.

Instead, teach your CGI script to output the image directly, depending on how it is called (or write a second one that does).

Comment: It's the graph method that creates the image, I don't think I can tell him to create the image in a canvas or something temporary. Anyway even if I do find a way to do that how can I display the image then? It's just a curiosity by the way, I need the images to be stored.

Comment: You'd create the image in a separate call.  Think of how HTTP works: everything with a separate URL is retrieved in a separate call, so you can create it when the call comes.